# How to get the result of If/ If else statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I don't know if I'm overseeing it or what, but I don't know how to get the result of an else if statement, for example, I have this code that I have been practicing:

In this case, the result would be "It's warm!", what I'd like to do is to create a code that would depend on the result, but the result it's not a variable, so how do I create a code responding to what was logged? for example if it logged: "It's warm!" I want to add something like "Turn on the AC." or "Turn on the heater" or something else. How do I do it?

```
let temperature = 36
if (temperature > 24) {
console.log ("It's warm!");
} else if (temperature < 24) {
    console.log ("It's cold!");    
} else {
    console.log ("It's cool!");
```

Comment: What do you mean by output? Why not set a variable?

Comment: There is no "result" of an `if` statement in JavaScript. You can set a variable, e.g., `tempWord`, to an appropriate value, e.g., `tempWord = 'cold'` and access it once outside the `if` statement.

Comment: After last console log, close '}' and it works

Answer (score 0):

You could just save it as a variable:

```
let temperature = 36;
const isCold = temperature < 24;
const isWarm = temperature > 24;
if (isWarm) {
    console.log("It's warm!");
} else if (isCold) {
    console.log("It's cold!");
} else {
    console.log("It's cool!");
}

if (isWarm) {
    console.log("Turn on the A/C!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set your code in the expresion block that are defined with `{}` after the if condition..

As example:

```js
let temperature = 36;
if (temperature > 24) {
  console.log("It's warm!");
  console.log("Turn on the AC.");
  // You can write coode base in this condition as much you want
  // or you can call another function
} else if (temperature < 24) {
  console.log("It's cold!");
} else {
  console.log("It's cool!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you mean, but if you want to output the temperature:

```
let temperature = 36
if (temperature > 24) {
console.log ("It's warm!", temperature, "degrees");
} else if (temperature < 24) {
    console.log ("It's cold!", temperature, "degrees");    
} else {
    console.log ("It's cool!", temperature, "degrees);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the result into a variable.

```js
let temperature = 36;
let result = '';
if (temperature > 24) {
  result = "It's warm!";
} else if (temperature < 24) {
  result = "It's cold!";
} else {
  result = "It's cool!";
}

console.log (result);
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining why the value on the result is ' ', wouldn't it be a falsy since it's a string without a value?

Comment: The value of result is only `’'` at the beginning. It will always be changed to another value by the assignments in the if/else blocks. It’s also not without value, it is an empty string. “Without value” is undefined or null. The empty string being falsy has no relevance here.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable in a function - pass the temperature into the fucntion and output the result - note the use of the `switch statement` that compares the inputted temp to the conditions and update the result string. This is what switch statements are for - to provide an alternative to nested or complex if else statments.

```js
function setTemperature(temp){
 let result = "It's ";
  switch (true) {
    case temp > 24:
    result += "warm!";
    break;
    
    case temp > 12:
    result += "cool!";
    break;
    
    default:
    result += "cold!";
  }
  return result;
}

    
console.log( setTemperature(36)); // gives "It's warm!"
console.log( setTemperature(16)); // It's cool!
console.log( setTemperature(6)); //It's cold!
```

Comment: Hey thank you for the insight, I had just started learning about functions and switch, going to come back to this later with a better understanding!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function like so:

```js
let temperature = 36;
function myFunct(temp){ // "myFunct" can be anything
    if (temp > 24) {
        return "It's warm!";
    } else if (temp < 24) {
        return "It's cold!";    
    } else {
        return "It's cool!";
    }
}

var t = myFunct(temperature); // get whether it's warm, cold, or cool

console.log(t); // tell the user if it's warm, cold, or cool

// do something!
if(t === "It's warm!"){
    // run something here if it's warm
} else if (t === "It's cold!"){
    // run something here if it's cold
} else {
    // run something here if it's cool
}
```

Though you could just run something inside the function or original if statement instead.

Hope this helped!